# document.documentElement.scrollTop = 100; is working fine in iOS13 and above version but not working iOS lower version and android

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Main document (Page) have fix height and width and is equal to size of device screen so no horizontal or vertical scroll.
While user try to add input and keyboard open i have to scroll document so user can see input box.
For that I have used document.documentElement.scrollTop = 100; (here i used fix value but it would be dynamic) and it's working fine in iOS13 and above version but not working iOS lower version and android.
I have also tried window.scrollTo but it also won't work.

Comment: `window.scrollTo()` is a function not a property that returns a value. Perhaps you're looking for `window.scrollY`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest `document.getElementById("INPUT_ID").scrollIntoView();`, as you won't have to calculate any offsets.